# Struct as ViewModel

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, struct

when working with Swift it's clear that we can do a lot of thing using struct instead of class. Nowadays, I'm working in a project that has MVVM pattern and it's going very well. However, I stopped to create class for my ViewModels and by now I'm writing it with structs and protocols. My question is, is it safe? There is something wrong on it? I had already google it, but I still not 100% sure about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's based on how you use the instance only, normally to use MVVM you only have 1 viewModel per viewController, if you don't make copy by assign it to other instance and work on that new instance, it will just be the same as using class viewModel, it's also the most basic difference between struct and class anyway

Comment: Yeah, that was my feeling. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks :)

Comment: Which one to use when view model is having some state and it gets update. In this case we need to assign the update struct every time to the view controller.